# Python loop for extracting feature from image does not run completely

Tags: python, for-loop, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I have the following piece of code, which uses Tesseract-OCR (python wrapper- tesserocr) to extract the font attributes from images containing text.

```
for image in image_list:
    print "Starting for ",image
    font_attribute_list = []
    with PyTessBaseAPI(oem=0) as api:
        image1 = PIL.Image.open(path+image)
        api.SetImage(image1)
        api.Recognize()
        iterator = api.GetIterator()
        font_attribute_list.append(iterator.WordFontAttributes())
    word_font_attribute_dataframe = word_font_attribute_dataframe.append([font_attribute_list[0]], ignore_index=True)
    image1.close()
```

This runs for only a few images and that number keeps on changing. Sometimes it runs for about 13-14 images, sometimes for about 100 and then just stops.
No error or anything. It just ends.
Sometimes it gives the error "Segmentation fault (core dumped)". I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

that all sounds like fun.  Normally when you get a segmentation fault it means that you are trying to do too many things at once and it's jamming up your memory.  It's possible that your code isn't just stopping without an error, it could still be going, just really really slowly.

It looks like you open an image in every iteration of that loop, so maybe all the open images are using up your working memory.  You could try closing the image before the end of the loop.

Comment: I'v tried closing them as well, still getting the error. 
It does not run very slowly, it finishes for one image in about a second and just stops after like 13 images , sometimes 100 images etc. 

P.S - Edited the code to include the close statement